# AWS: how to allow Lambda to call IP whitelisted API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a IP white-listed `Resource Policy` on a `AWS` `API Gateway` like below. Now I have a `Lambda` that needs to call this API but is currently correctly disallowed.

```
   {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "..."
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "...",
                "Condition": {
                    "NotIpAddress": {
                        "aws:SourceIp": [
                            "...",
                            "...",

                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The Lambda function is configured to access my VPC:

```
      VpcConfig:
        SubnetIds:
          - "subA"
          - "subB"
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - "sg1"
```

My question is two fold:

1. How should I change the `API Resource Policy` to allow access from this function? Replacing the white-listing policy with snippet below does not work. (`"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:... with an explicit deny"`)

```
  {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:..."
            ],
            "Condition" : {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                   "aws:SourceVpc": "{{ID of VPC attached to Lambda}}"
                }
            }
        }
```

2. Adding snippet above to the existing policy also breaks the existing white-listing policy (all access is denied with identical message as above). How do multiple policies next to each other compose? Do they? Is it an `and` or an `or` composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `SourceVpc` in the API Resource Policy is going to work, unless your API Gateway is a private VPC-only API.

Since your Lambda function is already running in a VPC, you need to simply add the IP addresses of your VPC NAT Gateways to the list of your API Gateway allowed IPs.